# My first jQuery plugin - blurStuff()

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugin

I've played with jQuery for some time now but have never written my own plugin.

A question was asked: "can I blur an image using jQuery?" and I thought this to be a decent candidate to play with.

Here's my code so far:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.blurStuff = function (options) {
        var defaults = {blurRadius:2, deblurOnHover:false};
        var settings = $.extend(defaults, options);

        $(this).wrap('<div data-blurimage />');

        var blurContainers = $(this).closest('[data-blurimage]');

        blurContainers.each(function () {
            var img = $(this).children();

            $(this).css({
                'width': img.width(),
                'height': img.height(),
                'overflow': 'hidden',
                'position': 'relative'
            });

            var clone = img.clone();
            clone.css({
                'opacity': 0.2,
                'position': 'absolute'
            });

            $(this).append(clone.clone().css({'left': +settings.blurRadius, 'top': +settings.blurRadius}));
            $(this).append(clone.clone().css({'left': -settings.blurRadius, 'top': +settings.blurRadius}));
            $(this).append(clone.clone().css({'left': +settings.blurRadius, 'top': -settings.blurRadius}));
            $(this).append(clone.clone().css({'left': -settings.blurRadius, 'top': -settings.blurRadius}));
        });

        if (settings.deblurOnHover == true) {
            blurContainers.hover(function () {
                $(this).children('img:gt(0)').toggle();
            });
        }

        return blurContainers;
    };
})(jQuery);
```

**In action: http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/xvvWj/**

Example usage:

```
$('img').blurStuff({deblurOnHover: true, blurRadius: 2});
```

My working logic is to wrap the selector in a parent container and then append 4 translucent clones to this, where each clone is positioned slightly off centre.

This works pretty well so far and I'm pleased with my progress but I can conceive a couple of potential bugs that I wanted some opinions on!

1. Is my approach reasonable? I realise that I'm appending an extra 4 elements to the DOM on each call which is not ideal (I could get away with using just two, laterally or diagonally, but I think 4 produces a better effect)...
2. What to do if a user passes a `fixed` position element? This will break existing flow.
3. Should I bother validating/sanity checking the parameter values? If so, how should I approach this? Previously I had a parameter called `blurOpacity` but I removed this because I realised that the wrong values (e.g. `1`) effectively "breaks" things.

Comment: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/11/essential-jquery-plugin-patterns/ Look at using native css blur if the browser supports it. http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters And look at css transforms.

Answer (score 5):

In the code I only would modify the variable declarations:

```
var defaults = {blurRadius:2, deblurOnHover:false},
settings = $.extend(defaults, options),
img, blurContainers, clone;
```

Personal preference, but you can read a discusion about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3684923/javascript-variables-declare-outside-or-inside-loop).

Answering your questions:

1. The efect work great. I think the approach is good, don't think
   that adding four elements would be a big cost.
2. You could check if the  has the fixed property to avoid breaking anything.
3. By the parameters you have rigth now I shouldn't bother. If you decide
   to add the opacity again it would be a good idea to check it. If
   greater than 0.x use the default instead.

Comment: hey, thanks, for sure I'm going to visit you on monday, at work :P

Answer (score 2):

overall it's pretty good! But I have a few minor points:

- The constant references to `$(this)` are bad. That call creates a jQuery collection each time. You could just save this as a variable.

  ```
  var $this = $(this);
  $this.append(...);
  $this.append(...);
  ```
- You could combine your defaults and settings to save a reference;

  ```
  var settings = $.extend({
    blurRadius: 2, 
    deblurOnHover: false
  }, options);
  ```

Comment: I'd probably argue that he should be using chaining rather than just caching `$this`

Comment: @megawac I am comfortable with the concept on caching but not on chaining, can you elaborate please?

Comment: @megawac Perhaps, but it doesn't help from a performance point of view. Calling `append` once with an array of elements would probably be better.

Comment: http://masonry.desandro.com/methods.html